# Hyper-V not Launching Ubuntu 17.10.1

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I'm following instructions for [Creating a Linux VM on Windows 10 with Hyper-V](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-run-linux-distros-windows-10-using-hyper-v).  I chose to download and use the Ubuntu 17.10.1 ISO on a "Generation 1" VM.  Everything is fine until I issue the "connect" command for my new VM.  The screen for the VM hangs, showing me nothing:

[image: VM started but hanging]

According to the instructions I was following, my attempt to connect with the VM should result in Ubuntu asking me installation questions, such as what language I'm using.  Nothing like that happens.

Any ideas?  I'm using Windows 10 Pro x64, version 1709.

Comment: What do you see on the screen if you do a reset from the action menu or reset button?  You could have a faulty ISO.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have activated "Secure boot" in your VM settings... deactivate it

Answer (score 3):

When you create a VM in Hyper-V it defaults to using a Microsoft Windows template for Secure Boot, which doesn't work with Linux. You should be able to boot the Ubuntu ISO by changing the template.

1. Open the settings for your VM
2. Under **Hardware**, select **Security**
3. In the **Secure Boot** section change the **Template** dropdown to **Microsoft UEFI Certificate Authority**
4. Apply the changes and boot your VM

**Note:** With Secure Boot enabled you will not be able to install the 3rd-party drivers for Ubuntu. You can disable Secure Boot by unchecking **Enable Secure Boot** as step 3 instead.